# Is it possible to $watch a directive's transcluded scope or even two way bind it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within a directive with transcluded scope it appears that $watch listeners do not trigger. Two way bindings also appear not to work. I'll paste the code I have of a simple example illustrating the issue as well as it's jsbin link. My question is: Is this possible? If so what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular tips</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <person header="header">
    <h2>{{header}}</h2>
    <p>Hello, I am {{person.name}} and,</p>
    <p>I am a {{person.profession}}</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Change me" ng-model="person.name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Change me" ng-model="person.profession" />
  </person>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.person = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    profession: 'Fake name'
  };

  $scope.header = 'Person';
})

.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      header: '='
    },
    transclude:true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('person', function(){
        console.log('person changed');
      }, true);
      scope.person = {
        name: 'Directive Joe',
        profession: 'Scope guy'
      };

      scope.header = 'Directive\'s header';
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are so many different way to do things with directive, can you be specific. thanks

Comment: Hi Tim. I've actually solved my particular use case without use $watch by binding the ng-keyup directive to the input I needed to watch. My question's aim is to understand if its possible to use $watch on a transcluded scope for the same reasons that its used within a regular scope, after all I could use ng-keyup for every input that I use in a directive's scope but I typically use $watch, perhaps I shouldn't?

Comment: it's good that you sorted it out. As far as I can understand the better option would be to use $observe. attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value) {
      console.log('ngModel has changed value to ' + value);
 }); If its attribute binding. However $watch is fine as well I guess